# Import columnar json in Excel using PowerQuery

Tags: powerquery

How would I import the following json

```json
{
    "Column1": ["r1c1", "r2c1", "r3c1"],
    "Column2": ["r1c2", "r2c2", "r3c2"],
    "Column3": ["r1c3", "r2c3", "r3c3"]
}
```

using PowerQuery and get the table in Excel:

[image]

?

### Notes:

I already tried without success Data\Connect to data...

[image]

... Into Table...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: data .. get data .. from file ... from JSON ... then  after review file ... close and load

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I already tried that :-) and a few other mashups without success

Comment: from your image, click the arrow atop the Value column to expand it

Comment: @horseyride: the json is NOT the "normal" row style json (aka `[{"column1": "r1c1", "column2": "r1c2"}, {"column1": "r2c1", "column2": "r2c2"}...]`). It's a "columnar style" json - each key represents a column P.S.: thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
let Source = Record.ToTable(Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\Temp\test.json"))),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.FromList([Value], null, {"contents"}), "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type)),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"contents", "Index"}, {"contents", "Index"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{"Value"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Name]), "Name", "contents"),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"})
in  #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]